# getParameter from JSP is not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp

I'm trying to send some information to my web service but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I will try explain it starting at with the following code:

```
<form id="update_delete2" method="post" action="maintenance_information.jsp" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                                                <span class="section">Question register content</span>

                                                <p>Insert an question <code>id</code> an then press the key <code>Enter</code> to load the register. 
                                                    Modify or review question register and then choose your action.
                                                </p>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="id4">Question ID <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                        <input type="number" id="id4" name="id4" required="required"
                                                               data-validate-minmax="10,100" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="title4">Title <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                        <input type="text" id="title4" name="title4" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="description4"> Description <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                        <textarea id="description4" required="required" name="description4" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="type4"> Question type <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 btn-group">
                                                        <label id="t1" name="t1" class="btn btn-default">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="type4" id="type4" value="Dashboard"> Dashboard
                                                        </label>
                                                        <label id="t2" name="t2" class="btn btn-default">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="type4" id="type4" value="App"> App
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input class="hidden" type="text" id="form_id" name="form_id">
                                                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                        <input id="update2" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">
                                                        <input id="delete2" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

This is my form, and I have a hidden input and it allows to know where is the operation that I have to do on my data base.
Depends on the button that I press it takes a value of "5" or "6" and I change this from Jquery with the following sentences:

```
$("#update2").click(function () {
    $("#form_id").val("5");
    $("#update_delete2").submit();
});

$("#delete2").click(function () {
    $("#form_id").val("6");
    $("#update_delete2").submit();
});
```

So curious because I have the same structure in another form and it is working and I have copied the same struct here but I have not been able to work this.

In the jsp file I get hidden input by id "form_id" with the following instruction:

```
request.getParameter(PageInfo.FORM_ID)
```

where PageInfo.FORM_ID is "form_id". The result is empty string "".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked (via browser's developer tools) if the expected value of `form_id` is sent in the request after `submit()`?

Comment: No, but I do the same thing in another form with same structure and It works. Theoretically, It should work, but just not here. The problem is that the value is not sended due to some bug in form.

Comment: EDIT: I have checked the value and it returns a "" (empty string) in request and before summit it have "5", the value to identify my operation.